# Prestashop - AuthController.php is not receiving input values

Tags: php, prestashop, recaptcha

I'm trying to add google reCaptcha to prestashop's opc registration page, I have the checkbox setup and it's working however the php file is not receiving the captcha response. Let me explain. Here's what I've done so far: In my header.tpl I added

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

In order-opc-new-account.tpl, I added

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[my_public_key]"></div>
```

In my AuthController.php I added

```
if (Tools::isSubmit('submitAccount') OR Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount')) //if statement was already present
{   
    // captcha code I added
    $reCaptchaUrl='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $reCaptchaSecret = '[my_secret_key]';
    $reCaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $verifyCaptcha = file_get_contents($reCaptchaUrl."?secret=".$reCaptchaSecret."&response=".$reCaptchaResponse."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $captchaReply = json_decode($verifyCaptcha);

    if(isset($captchaReply->success) AND $captchaReply->success == true){
        $logger = new FileLogger(0);
        $logger->setFilename(_PS_ROOT_DIR_."/log/debug.log");
        $logger->logDebug("Captcha was successful: ".$reCaptchaResponse);
    } else {
        //captcha failed
        $logger = new FileLogger(0);
        $logger->setFilename(_PS_ROOT_DIR_."/log/debug.log");
        $logger->logDebug("Captcha failed: ".$reCaptchaResponse);
    }

    // ... prestashop registration code
}
```

I learned with the debugging messages that `$reCaptchaResponse` variable is actually coming empty everytime, even if the captcha has been checked. Any ideas why?

**Edit**: The form actually sends the data to `authentication.php` which has the following lines

```
require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
ControllerFactory::getController('AuthController')->run();
```

My guess is that this piece of code *forwards* the form data to `AuthController.php` but it only forwards fields that it's been told to forward. It does not recognizes the new recaptcha field and doesn't forward that data to the file. So I would need to find who decides which data get's forwarded.

Comment: hm, maybe try `$reCaptchaResponse = Tools::getValue('g-recaptcha-response');`? - also please obfuscate the API keys!!

Comment: No good, it didn't work. Please see the original post for more info. BTW the keys were public and for testing purposes so I didn't bother hiding them. [Googe Dev Guide](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-v2-what-should-i-do)

Comment: did you make sure, with network tab of dev tools for example, that `g-recaptcha-response` is being posted when you submit the form?  - my bad, didn't know about the testing keys

Comment: No I didn't check that. But I've given up on it, I used another method to solve the problem of spam registrations.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI"></div>` is in the FORM element.

Comment: Yes ofcourse it is in the form element. My best guess is AuthController doesnot get the data directly so I doesn't receive this new field